# Invoke a higher order function with parameters

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to define a callback method in Kotlin which has accepts two parameters. How do I declare a lambda for the actual function invokation in a variable?

```
// actual method
fun foo(a : String, b : String) {
    // do something
}

// syntax error here
val callback : (String, String) -> Unit = foo(a, b)

// invoke method
callback.invoke("a", "b")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fun foo(a : String, b : String) {
    // do something
}

val callback : (String, String) -> Unit = ::foo
// or val callback = { a: String, b: String -> foo(a, b) }

fun main() {
    callback.invoke("a", "b")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you do here is attempting to call a Unit a `(String, String) -> Unit`. Aside the non-existent variables, you get a Unit when you invoke the function.

If you're familiar with Java (which is slightly more understandable), you have:

```
void foo(String a, String b) { ... }
BiConsumer consumer = foo(a, b);
```

Which isn't allowed, because a void isn't a, in the case of Java, BiConsumer. Equivalently, in your case, a (I honestly don't remember what the functions were named, but it's something along the lines of) KFunction2 isn't a Unit.

To get the actual method reference, you need to use `::`. By using `.` in either Java or Kotlin, you **invoke** the function; you're not returning the function itself, which I assume is your intention.

```
val callback: (String, String) -> Unit = ::foo
```

Unlike Java, you're not required to have anything on the left side of the operator. If you later need to scope your method (i.e. it's in an instance), you'd place that on the left:

```
var someClassWithAFunction = ....
var callback: (String, String) -> Unit = someClassWithAFunction::foo
```

But the specifics of usage beyond the scope of the question isn't too important at the moment.

Once you have the method reference, you can invoke it like a regular function (what you originally did when assigning it - `callback(...)`). However, you need to scope it with a function for it to be valid syntax, but I'm assuming you're already doing that and it's just for the sake of an MCVE it's written the way it is.